What happens if we cancel "pip install" in the middle of installation?
When installing packages using pip (e.g., pip install -r requirements.txt), what happens if we cancel the process in the middle of the installation? Does pip automatically rollback to the state before the installation started?

No, it doesn't. You might end up with a half installed package that is not registered as installed and can not be uninstalled directly.

If the process of installing packages using pip (e.g. via the command pip install -r requirements.txt) is interrupted in the middle of execution, pip does not automatically roll back to the state before the installation began.
Already installed packages will remain in place: if any package was installed before the interruption, it will remain installed.
So if an error occurred or you manually interrupted the installation, just enter the command again.
pip install -r requirements.txt  # pip will only attempt to install packages that are not fully installed

